# Write down the third root, z3, of the equation.

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Given that z1 = 2 and z2 = 1 + i√3 are roots of the cubic equation z^3 + bz^2 + c*z + d = 0 where b, c, d are real numbers:

Write down the third root, z3, of the equation.

The answer: 
1 –  i√3

Doubt:
 I don't know how to get to this answer.

Comment: If a polynomial with **real coefficients** has a complex root, it has as well its complex conjugate as a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is a root of your polynomial, then, by definition,
$$
r^3+br^2+cr+d=0
$$
Take complex conjugates:
$$
0=\bar{0}=\overline{r^3+br^2+cr+d}=\bar{r}^3+b\bar{r}^2+c\bar{r}+d
$$
(because $\bar{b}=b$ and the same for the other coefficients, which are supposed to be real). Hence also $\bar{r}$ is a root.

This yields nothing new for the root $z_1=2$, but it says that $\overline{z_2}=1-i\sqrt{3}$ *is* a root. Hence $z_3=1-i\sqrt{3}$, because the polynomial has at most three roots.